# setOnTouchlistener for an image view

Tags: android, image, touch, listener

i am loading an image from gallery through startActivityForResult()
and loading the image in onActivity(). Can't i implement a
touchlistener for that image? for reference see below.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
        ...... 
        ...... 
          Bitmap bitmapPreview = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileSrc); //load preview image

         setimage.setImageBitmap(BitmapPreview);
     setimage.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image touced!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
    }
    });
```

Comment: The method setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnTouchListener(){})                                                 i get this error message...any idea???

Comment: @jxcn Why are you return false and if check it using System.out.print("image is touched");

Comment: Do you have a custom type also named OnTouchListener?

Comment: like alextsc the listener needs to implement the imports...

Comment: and can i implement my onTouch like this??? inside onActivity??? cause i added a toast and ran, it showed force close error while selecting the image from gallery...

Comment: the toast that i used Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Image touced!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that you imported the listener correctly, you need

```
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
```

at the top of your file with the other imports.