# OnClickListener = down + up? Android

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

OnClickListener is button press down + button let go up. Is there anyway to get it to go off with just button press down?

I still suck at reading [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html). Doesn't mention anything about this and I don't know how to go about finding something that could help.

[OnLongClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html) says `Called when a view has been clicked and held.`

### **Since my question was answered fairly quickly, does anyone know why I would get this error when I change my onClick to onTouch?**

```
The method setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnTouchListener(){})
```

Comment: Sounds like there should be an `On?DownListener`

Comment: @EGHDK Okay, I just pasted your error message in internet search. :) always use `Ctrl+Shift+O` to import necessary classes. [import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483283/setontouchlistener-for-an-image-view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you need to use an [onTouchListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html).

**Update:**

Please refer this tutorial on how to use this:

http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/3279/android-the-basics-32-androids-ontouchlistener-and-motionevent/

Comment: `The method setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnTouchListener(){})`

Comment: [import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483283/setontouchlistener-for-an-image-view)

Comment: Interesting... I thought eclipse would've helped me along, but you are correct @MKJParekh

Comment: Yeah, I've never had eclipse fail to tell me that I don't have an import. Oh well, I get what I pay for with eclipse I guess.

Comment: @EGHDK Do you pay for eclipse, I thought its a freeware.. :D